# Proof for claim that mixtures of Gaussian distributions are dense in the set of probability distributions

Tags: reference-request

I've been trying to find a proof for the claim that

> Mixtures of Gaussian distributions are dense in the set of probability distributions, with respect to the weak topology.

but I have failed to do so. Does anyone know where I can read more about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found something.

Readers interested in this problem should check out ["Approximation of Probability Distributions by Convex Mixtures of Gaussian Measures"](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2010-138-07/S0002-9939-10-10340-2/S0002-9939-10-10340-2.pdf) and the references found therein.